# Encrypt and decrypt a file in Java with DES algorithm

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to do an exercise to encrypt a file.txt with a DES algorithm. I must save the generated key in a file without extension. I think this part is well solved. But I have troubles to decrypting the encrypted file using the same key. I'm getting the error: "Given final block not properly padded".

Exercise:
1. Encryption Program: Read a text file, encrypts it using the DES algorithm and the result is written to a new file, another file stored in the key used for encryption.
2. decryption program: read the program saved by the encryption key, decrypts the text stored by the encryption program and displays it on the screen.

NOTES: uses FileInputStream and FileOutputStream, performs encryption in blocks of 8 bytes and performs decryption in blocks of 16 bytes.

**ENCRYPTING**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class Encrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

            FileOutputStream fosKey = new FileOutputStream("..\\KEY");
            SecretKeyFactory keyfac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            DESKeySpec keyspec = (DESKeySpec) keyfac.getKeySpec(key, DESKeySpec.class);
            fosKey.write(keyspec.getKey());
            fosKey.close();

            Cipher crypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            crypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("..\\File.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("..\\FileCrypted.txt");
            byte[] arrayBytes = new byte[8];
            int bytesReads;
            while ((bytesReads = fis.read(arrayBytes)) != -1) {
                fos.write(crypt.doFinal(arrayBytes), 0, bytesReads);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**DECRYPTING**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class Decrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileInputStream fisKey = new FileInputStream("..\\KEY");
            byte[] arrayKey = new byte[fisKey.available()];
            fisKey.read(arrayKey);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(arrayKey, "DES");

            Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("..\\FileCrypted.txt");
            byte[] encText = new byte[16];
            int bytesReads;
            while ((bytesReads = fis.read(encText)) != -1) {
                fis.read(decrypt.doFinal(encText), 0, bytesReads);
            }
            fis.close();
            System.out.println(new String(encText));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always use a fully qualified Cipher string, because `Cipher.getInstance("DES");` may have different defaults based on the security provider, which might break compatibility across multiple JVM's. It most likely defaults to `Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");`

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `update()` method for the intermediate encrypt calls, and only use `doFinal()` on the last call. This goes for both encrypt and decrypt.

**DES** - in ECB or CBC mode -always uses block size of **8 bytes** (both encrypt and decrypt). If **padding** is active, **additional data** (1-8 bytes) will be appended to ensure a block size of 8 when you do the `doFinal()`. If padding is not active on the cipher, you need to ensure data have been provided as a multiple of 8 bytes when you do the `doFinal()`.

The `update()` allows you to handle data to the encryption without aligning to the 8 byte block size, as it is just buffered up until it have data for a full block. The `doFinal()` flushes any excessive bytes that might be in the buffer for encryption and applies any padding that may be in effect.

---

Please notice that DES is **not considered secure anymore**, so it should not be used for any serious security.